# Is Address Space Layout Randomization applied on a forked process

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

Say I fork a process from another process. Will Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) be applied on it in an OS which has ASLR set?

Note that I am talking about the case where I don't call execve function after doing fork.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

However note that after `fork` both parent and child have the same randomization applied to them (they are copies of each other after all!).

If the child and parent are to call `mmap(NULL, ...)`, *then* their address maps will start to diverge.

Update:

> Isn't your statement contradictory?

Not at all. Immediately after `fork`, the parent and child address spaces are identical (that's the definition of what `fork` does). But the ASLR is still in effect for both the parent and the child. The randomization can't "go back in time" and randomize decisions that have already been made, but any future decisions (such as where to place next `mmap`) *will* be randomized, and will likely result in different outcome for parent and child.

> Does it have to do with basic mmap or OS writers introduce randomness in mmap as well for security?

Perhaps you don't understand what ASLR is?

In short, with ASLR on, the OS will r[andomize placement of main stack, and placement of any non-`MAP_FIXED` mmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

By the time you `fork`, the main stack placement has long been determined, so parent and child will have the same. The future `mmap` are the only things that can (and will be) affected by ASLR going forward.

Comment: You first say yes, and then say they will be the same. Isn't your statement contradictory? or do you mean that parent process's address layout will be changed dynamically at the point of fork call to match that one of the forked process? Looks very unlikely. And why mmap makes them diverge? Does it have to do with basic mmap or OS writers introduce randomness in mmap as well for security?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: the child has the same randomization as the parent had: even if both processes start with the same memory map, that memory map is random. On a different scale, `preload -r` sets random preload addresses for libraries, every time the library is loaded the loader will try to load it at the same address, but that address is still random (and different from other systems with the same distro).

Comment: Accepting an answer that is complete and courteous strikes me as good style.

Comment: So what you mean is in the following code with address space randomisation `int a; if (fork() == 0)
  { printf(“%d\n”, &a); }
  else { printf(“%d\n”, &a); }`, the values printed by the parent and child will be the same but they will differ across multiple builds.

Comment: @Nishant Builds have nothing to do with this. Values will always be the same between parent and child. But if you start 3 different parents (instances of the exact *same* binary), you can expect to observe 6 values forming 3 distinct pairs (in other words, parent 1, 2, and 3 will get each own randomized value, but child 1 will print the same value as parent 1, etc.)

Comment: "the parent and child address spaces are identical (that's the definition of what fork does)"

Maybe mentioning copy-on-write would help explain why it is unreasonable to expect anything else